# Prove: $\sum_k k \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{k} = n\binom{m+n-1}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics

I usually use *double counting* to prove such statements, e.g. $\sum_k \binom{r}{k} \binom{s}{n-k} = \binom{r+s}{n}$. I'm also thinking of a way to prove it using the following property of the binomials.

$\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n}{m}\binom{n-1}{m-1}$

What is your idea/solution?

Comment: What is the question here? It sounds as if you already know how to prove the identity.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, I know how to prove the identity, but I don't know *exactly* how to prove $\sum_k k\binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{k} = n\binom{m+n-1}{n}$. I think I'm getting somewhere with the answer below, but any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Vandermonde Identity** which is derivable from *double counting* or the expansion $(1+x)^s (1+x)^r = (1+x)^{s+r}$ is as follows.

$\sum_k \binom{r}{k} \binom{s}{n-k} = \binom{r+s}{n}.$

Now in the VI, put $r=m$ and $s=n-1$. So we have

$\sum_k \binom{m}{k} \binom{n-1}{n-k} = \binom{m+n-1}{n}.$

Multiplying both sides of this equation by $n$, 

$\sum_k n \binom{m}{k} \binom{n-1}{n-k}=n\binom{m+n-1}{n-k}.$

Because

$\sum_k k \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{k} = \sum_k n\binom{n-1}{k-1} \binom{m}{k} = \sum_k n\binom{n-1}{n-k} \binom{m}{k}$,

then

$\sum_k k \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{k} =n\binom{m+n-1}{n-k}.$

$\square$

Thanks to @user152715 for his guidance

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^r (1+x)^s=(1+x)^{r+s}$...(1)

As, $k{n \choose k}{m \choose k}=n{n-1 \choose k-1}{m \choose k}=n{n-1 \choose n-k}{m \choose k}$.

Now from (1), the result follows.

Comment: Are you suggesting this to prove $\sum_k k\binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{k} = n \binom{m+n-1}{n}$?

Comment: yes, just split $k{n \choose k}=n{n-1 \choose k-1}$. Then apply that.